# Buildroot busybox limited command set

Tags: busybox, buildroot

I'm using the *raspberrypi0_defconfig* to create an image for the Raspberry Pi Zero-W. I'm having a number of issues, but the first one I want to address is why my Busybox shell has so little build in commands?

```
# help
Built-in commands:
------------------
        . : [ [[ alias bg break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec
        exit export false fg getopts hash help history jobs kill let
        local printf pwd read readonly return set shift source test times
        trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait
```

For example, at the very least I'd like to have the *ls* command added.
In the menuconfig I cannot find these options for Busybox, however, there is a configuration file listed, pointing to package/busybox/busybox.config.

This file has a header that suggest it's configurable somewhere (make config seems to be a text-only version of make menuconfig):

```
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# Busybox version: 1.27.1
# Sun Jul 30 15:27:03 2017
#
```

and among other things has

```
CONFIG_LS=y
```

So, the two questions are:

- Why don't I have build-in commands that seem to be configured?
- Where (preferably in menuconfig?) can I configure Busybox?

Comment: Can you not build Busybox from source?

Comment: I think buildroot does that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BusyBox help apparently doesn't display every available command. Ls, and presumably other commands were in my case actually available.

The default consoles settings prevented keyboard input to come through correctly in some cases, resulting in an erratic shell behaviour, which caused it to seem commands were not present.

After changing the default settings *TTY* from "console" to "tty1" and the *baudrate* to "38400" everything, including the *ls* command worked fine.